# Unsupported query for Continuous Query Notification

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a View Object `A` that i am using as an `Accessor` in a `List of value` in view object `VO`. `A` has a view criteria too to filter search. Auto Refresh is set to `True`. 
Now when ever i open the List of Values on `VO` and search the List of value using i am getting this error

```
Unsupported query for Continuous Query Notification
```

Here is my query for `A` ( which is (again) being used as List of values `accessor`

```
select e.employee_id,       
            e.first_name emp_name ,      
            d.department_name,      
            j.job_title,      
            g.grade_name      
            from       
   hr_employees e,      
   hr_departments d,      
   hr_jobs j,      
   prl_grade_header g       
   where e.department_id = d.department_id      
   and e.job_id = j.job_id(+)      
   and e.grade_id = g.grade_header_id(+)
```

My query does not have anything that can cause this error as per oracle documentation.
What is going on wrong, how can i get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1):

As per Oracle one of the objects do not reference to a tables name directly.
Maybe you are using synonyms instead of tables in your query.

**And There is a restriction at the database level, that prevents using synonyms for Object Change Notification (OCN) registration.**

Comment: according to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_cqn.htm#BDCEHIDF `You can use synonyms in OCN registrations, but not in QRCN registrations.`So your answer makes no sense.. but it works.. I can confirm that on 11g you can't use synonyms.